# I keep getting "The response ended prematurely" when invoking Web api in .net core tests

Tags: .net-core, docker-compose, httpclient, fluent-docker

I'm using Specflow as BDD testing framework and Fluent docker to spin up API container before each tests using docker compose file.

I put a breakpoint before sending a http request to test if the container is up and my app is running perfectly.

I open app swagger and hit endpoints and everything works. I added http request logging to check if request url is valid. Everything seems to be configured properly until this line:

`var response = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(UserEndpoint, request);`

This is console log

[image]and this is my app Program.cs

```
using Ardalis.ListStartupServices;
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using UserSegmentation.Core;
using UserSegmentation.Infrastructure;
using UserSegmentation.Infrastructure.Data;
using UserSegmentation.Web;
using Serilog;
using UserSegmentation.Application;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Host.UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory());

builder.Host.UseSerilog((_, config) => config.ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration));

// builder.Services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
// {
//   options.CheckConsentNeeded = _ => true;
//   options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
// });

var connectionString =
  builder.Configuration
    .GetConnectionString("SqliteConnection"); //Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

builder.Services.AddDbContext(connectionString!);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
// add list services for diagnostic purposes - see https://github.com/ardalis/AspNetCoreStartupServices
builder.Services.Configure<ServiceConfig>(config =>
{
  config.Services = new List<ServiceDescriptor>(builder.Services);

  // optional - default path to view services is /listallservices - recommended to choose your own path
  config.Path = "/listservices";
});


builder.Host.ConfigureContainer<ContainerBuilder>(containerBuilder =>
{
  containerBuilder.RegisterModule(new DefaultCoreModule());
  containerBuilder.RegisterModule(
    new DefaultInfrastructureModule(builder.Environment.EnvironmentName == "Development"));
  containerBuilder.RegisterModule(
    new ApplicationModule());
});

builder.Services.AddHealthChecks();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
  app.UseSwagger();
  app.UseSwaggerUI();
  app.UseShowAllServicesMiddleware();
}

// app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.UseFluentValidationExceptionHandler();

app.MapHealthChecks("/healthz");

// Seed Database
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
  var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

  try
  {
    var context = services.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>();
    context.Database.EnsureCreated();
    SeedData.Initialize(services);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
    logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred seeding the DB. {exceptionMessage}", ex.Message);
  }
}

app.Run();
```

My hooks config

```
[BeforeScenario]
  public void SetupClient()
  {
    var config = LoadConfiguration();
    var apiUrl = config["Users.Api:BaseAddress"] ?? "http://localhost:8080";
    var httpClient = new HttpClient(new LoggingHandler(new HttpClientHandler())) {
      BaseAddress = new Uri(apiUrl)
    };
    
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("accept", "*/*");
    _objectContainer.RegisterInstanceAs(httpClient);

    var dockerConfig = new DockerConfiguration();
    _objectContainer.RegisterInstanceAs(dockerConfig);
  }

  
  [BeforeTestRun]
  public static void DockerComposeUp(DockerConfiguration dockerHandling)
  {
    dockerHandling.DockerComposeUp();
  }
  
  [AfterTestRun]
  public static void DockerComposeDown(DockerConfiguration dockerHandling)
  {
    dockerHandling.DockerComposeDown();
  }
```

My docker config

```
_compositeService = new Builder()
      .UseContainer()
      .UseCompose()
      .FromFile(dockerConfigurationFile)
      .WaitForHttp("user-segmentation", "http://localhost:8080/healthz", 
        continuation: (resp, _) => resp.Code == HttpStatusCode.OK ? 0 : 2000)
      .RemoveOrphans()
      .Build()
      .Start();
```